# Checking a cell in DataGridView for any Char

Tags: c#, csv, datagridview, null

I have made a crossword like program which reads csv files into a DataGridView and want to check if the cell contains a character and change that cell to white and leave the remaining empty cells black.   Is there an easy way to check if a cell contains a character and then set that cell to white?

The following code seems to set all cells to white:

```
for (int i = 0; i < crozzleDisplay.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < crozzleDisplay.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                //crozzleDisplay[i, j].ReadOnly = true;
                if (crozzleDisplay[i, j].Value != null)
                    FormatCell(i, j);
            }
        }
```

Comment: String.IsNullOrEmpty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try doing this

```
if (crozzleDisplay[i, j].Value != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(crozzleDisplay[i, j].Value.toString()))
                    FormatCell(i, j);
```

not sure will compile didnt check

Answer (score 0):

A slightly more succinct and cleaner way would be:

```
string cellValue = crozzleDisplay[i, j].Value == null ? string.Empty : crozzleDisplay[i, j].Value.ToString();

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(cellValue))
    FormatCell(i, j);
```